# Consulta con MAX y COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla donde almaceno los id de películas (id_pel) y los id de actores (id_ac), para relacionar películas con actores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener la película o películas en la/s que intervienen más actores

Con esta consulta:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id_AC) AS 'actores' FROM pelisactores GROUP BY id_pel
```

Obtengo cuántos actores intervienen en cada película y si a esa consulta le agrego al final lo siguiente:

```
ORDER BY actores DESC LIMIT 1
```

Obtengo la película con más actores, pero sólo me muestra un registro. Si tengo por ejemplo 3 películas donde trabajan 7 actores quiero que me muestre las 3, si de verdad son las películas donde más actores trabajan, pero con ORDER BY actores DESC LIMIT 1 sólo me mostraría un registro

Con esta otra consulta:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id_AC) AS 'actores' FROM pelisactores GROUP BY id_pel HAVING COUNT(actores) >= 7
```

Obtengo todas aquellas películas donde trabajan más de 7 actores, pero cómo hago la consulta para obtener la película o películas donde trabajan más actores?

Esta consulta me da error:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id_AC) AS 'actores' FROM pelisactores GROUP BY id_pel HAVING MAX(COUNT(actores))
```

No estoy colocando bien el MAX y el COUNT... cómo se haría?

Gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara: sugiero que de entrada expliques el enunciado completo de lo que quieres, porque te pierdes explicando el problema, por partes, desde un código problemático. Si quieres una lista con los IDs de películas puedes incorporar un `GROUP_CONCAT(id_pel) AS peliculas` a la consulta. Si no es eso lo que quieres explica qué tipo de resultado esperas obtener, poniendo un ejemplo del set de datos.

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener los películas con mas de n actores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En primer lugar, veamos cual es el máximo de actores de todas las peliculas

```
SELECT MAX(T.actores)
       FROM (SELECT id_pel, 
                    COUNT(id_AC) AS actores
                    FROM pelisactores 
                    GROUP BY id_pel
       ) T
```

Ahora, sabiendo esto, simplemente debemos listar las películas que tengan esta cantidad máxima de actores:

```
SELECT T.id_pel
       FROM (SELECT id_pel, 
                    COUNT(id_AC) AS actores
                    FROM pelisactores 
                    GROUP BY id_pel
       ) T
       WHERE T.actores = (SELECT MAX(actores)
                                 FROM (SELECT id_pel, 
                                              COUNT(id_AC) AS actores
                                              FROM pelisactores 
                                              GROUP BY id_pel
                                 ) TT
                         )
```

Comment: Vaya, pensaba que la consulta sería más sencilla. He tenido que ponerle a su código en el segundo FROM, después de cerrrar el paréntesis, otro alias a la consulta (por ejemplo TT) y luego en el SELECT hacer referencia a ese alias (SELECT MAX(TT.actores))... y funciona perfectamente. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Podría hacer un INNER JOIN justo al final? Estoy tratando de hacer un INNER JOIN con la tabla peliculas para que me muestre también el nombre de la película pero me da error, me dice que algo está mal en la sintaxis

Comment: Si puedes perfectamente solo recuerda darle un alias a la tabla de peliculas y el `on` sería sobre ` T.id_pel`

Answer (score 3):

Una alternativa, es usar las funciones `RANK()` o `DENSE_RANK()` para definir el órden.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
     SELECT *, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY actores DESC) orden
     FROM (
           SELECT id_pel, 
                  COUNT(id_AC) AS 'actores'
           FROM pelisactores 
           GROUP BY id_pel
          ) a
    )b
WHERE orden = 1;
```

Comment: OK. Lo que está dentro del segundo FROM obtiene todas las películas y el número de actores que intervienen en cada una de ellas. Pero la función DENSE_RANK() no la entiendo, tampoco por qué orden es igual a uno abajo del todo en el WHERE... Me lo podrías explicar un poco?. Gracias.

Comment: Vale ya lo explicaron más abajo. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas MySQL 8 o superior, puedes valerte de CTE's y funciones de ventana para lograr el objetivo.

Te explico en ejemplo a continuación:

- En el primer CTE, llamado `Resumen`, hago el típico resumen para obtener la cantidad de actores por película
- En el segundo CTE me valgo del resultado obtenido en `Resumen` y de la [función `dense_rank()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) para numerar las filas basándome en el número de actores. `dense_rank` tiene la ventaja que otorga la misma numeración para todas las filas que tengan el mismo valor en los campos por los que ordeno, en este caso, la cantidad de actores.
- Finalmente obtengo todas las películas que tienen *rango* 1, que son las que tienen más actores, pero no solo obtengo el `id_pel` sino que estoy haciendo de una vez un *join* con una hipotética tabla de películas para obtener el nombre de las mismas.

```
with
Resumen as (
select id_pel, count(id_ac) as CantidadActores
  from pelisactores
 group by id_pel
)
, Clasificacion as (
select *, dense_rank() over (order by CantidadActores desc) dRank
  from Resumen
)
select Peliculas.Nombre, Clasificacion.CantidadActores
  from Clasificacion
       inner join Peliculas on Peliculas.id = Clasificacion.id_pel
 where dRank = 1
```

PD. Si bien hay ya otras respuestas que *solucionan* el problema correctamente, he agregado esta ya que no hacían uso de CTE's y, en mi opinión, usarlos no solo es es elegante, sino deja código mucho más fácil de entender y de mantener.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!